# Regex- Exclude middle pattern

Tags: python, regex, excel, matching

I'm struggling with excluding or ignoring a certain pattern.

In excel there are many timestamps followed by an ID

i.e.

`[0:02:25] 10652A`

sometimes there is a mistake where it is mixed up like this

`1 [0:03:23] 0652A`

Here the `1` belongs to `0652A` , so it should be `10652A.....`

How can I complete my code so that these mistakes (the middle timestamp part) can be ignored to match the id correctly?

This is what I've got so far:

```
starting_digits = re.search(r"^(\d+)", prefix)
id_code = re.search(r"(\d{2,4}.{1,3}):", prefix).group(1)
```

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for remove all text between square brackets.

> \[.*\]

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
# prefix = "1 [0:03:23] 0652A"
mobj = re.search(r"(\w+)?\s*\[(.*)\]\s*(\w+)", prefix)

id_code = mobj.group(1) + mobj.group(3) if mobj.group(1) else mobj.group(3)
timestamp = mobj.group(2)

print(id_code, timestamp)
```

This prints:

```
10652A 0:02:25
```

You can test the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/UdMUC3/2).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of finding the content of the ID, you can simply erase the timestamp part which matches `\s*\[[\d:]+\]\s*`

- any amount of space
- left square bracket
- more than one `digits/:`
- right square bracket
- any amount of space

```
reg = r"\s*\[.*\]\s*"

prefix = "[0:03:23] 0652A"
print(re.sub(reg, "", prefix))  # 0652A

prefix = "1 [0:03:23] 0652A"
print(re.sub(reg, "", prefix))  # 10652A
```